intersection cylinder and plane and sinusoidal function
A cylindrical wooden broomstick with a diameter of $d$ wrapped in A4 paper is cut at an angle of $\alpha$. Depending on the cutting angle, the upper edge of the surface can be represented.
a) Determine a functional equation that can describe the upper edge of the developed surface.
b) Describe the influence of the diameter and the cutting angle on the parameters of the general sine function
By the graphs I see that upper edge of the developed surface represents like sinusoidal function with period $d\pi$ and amplitude $\frac{d}{2tg(\alpha)}$. But I am not sure that developed surface is really represents by sinusoidal function. I cut the real sheet of paper and don't get sinusoidal function.


What is wrong about the ellipse structure of the cut?
